# Order by string with numbers

Tags: sqlite, order-by

I need to order the query using a pattern that mixes text and numbers. This is the default `ORDER BY` which is "correct" if not considering the entire numbers. But as you can see, at the end the order in not correct since `52 > 9` and same comparison should be applied at the number after the `:`. How I can make this comparison?

```
OEBPS/Text/3.html#point(/1/4/2/20/1:353)
OEBPS/Text/6.html#point(/1/4/2/88/1:348)
OEBPS/Text/7.html#point(/1/4/2/33:5)
OEBPS/Text/8.html#point(/1/4/2/13:5)
OEBPS/Text/8.html#point(/1/4/2/14/1:1232)
OEBPS/Text/8.html#point(/1/4/2/14/1:1813)
OEBPS/Text/8.html#point(/1/4/2/17:5)
OEBPS/Text/8.html#point(/1/4/2/18/1:262)
OEBPS/Text/8.html#point(/1/4/2/21:6)
OEBPS/Text/8.html#point(/1/4/2/30/1:334)
OEBPS/Text/8.html#point(/1/4/2/42/1:613)
OEBPS/Text/8.html#point(/1/4/2/52/3:360)
OEBPS/Text/8.html#point(/1/4/2/9:6)
```

Each numerical field should be sorted based on its position. What I mean is that /1/4/2/9:6 should come first then /1/4/2/52/3:360 since 9 < 52. And OEBPS/Text/3.html before OEBPS/Text/8.html since 3 < 8.

Comment: Hi, and weicome to dba.se! Do you want all of the digits to sort numerically or just the ones in the 2nd (sometimes 3rd) to last numerical field to sort?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Each numerical field should be sorted based on its position. What I mean is that `/1/4/2/9:6` should come first then `/1/4/2/52/3:360` since `9 < 52`. And `OEBPS/Text/3.html` before `OEBPS/Text/8.html` since `3 < 8`.

Comment: OK, can you get `OEBPS/Text/8.html` and also have `OEBPS/Text/18.html`? This is chapters in a book or similar? And then sections, subsections &c.?

Comment: Yes it's from my Kobo sqlite database

Comment: What are your programming skills? I was pursuing a an approach using regular expressions (see [here](https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean/blob/main/docs/re.md), but it is a poor implementation) PostgreSQL's regexes would do it. The only thing I can suggest at this juncture is that you write code to zerofill  (say 4 - you're unlikely to have 10,000 chapters, sections, subsections &c...)  the numbers in your string, so 8 -> 0008, 23 -> 0023 &c. That way your strings will sort as per the numerical value of the numbers and not just on their first character!

Comment: not sure how to do it using sqlite

Comment: That's my point - either you implement your own version of `REGEXP_INSTR()/REGEXP_REPLACE()` (difficult, I would suggest) or you do it via your favourite coding environment. Or if there aren't too many, you could do it with `REPLACE()` - but that's tedious and error-prone!

Comment: If you are allowed to, one way to do it, is to store leading zeros.  Personally, that's how I would do it.  You can always strip them for display.  For example, /01/04/02/09:06